# Coding math quiz in PHP (radio buttons not working)

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I'm coding a final project for my PHP class in which the user takes a math quiz based on Algebra and Calculus questions. The questions and question choices are all stored in a table and that aspect is fine.

Basically I have a loop that iterates ten times which pulls ten questions and ten answers choices from my database. I also printed a radio button for each answer choice.

However, the form only lets me select one radio button on the whole page. So say I select choice B on one question and then choice A on the second question, the 'circle' in that first radio button will go unchecked.

```
while (count($list) < 10){
    do { //this is where we pull questions from database
    $randomInt = rand(2,$rowcount); //random int is inbetween 2 and numbers of rows
    $sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM `math` WHERE `bid` =  \"" . $randomInt . "\" AND `acategory` = \"" . $category . "\"  ";
    $sqlSelectQuery = mysqli_query($link,$sqlselect);
    $numOfGoodQuestions = mysqli_num_rows($sqlSelectQuery);
    } while ($numOfGoodQuestions == 0); //if it returns blank field, it will loop again

    if (in_array($randomInt,$list)){ //if it pulls duplicate number, continue
        continue;
        } 
    else {
        //use fetch function
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSelectQuery);
        $questionNumber = $questionNumber + 1;
        $strQuestionNumber = (string)$questionNumber;
        $slots = array();
        array_push($slots,$row['aanswer']); //pushes answer choices into slots array
        array_push($slots,$row['awrong1']);
        array_push($slots,$row['awrong2']);
        array_push($slots,$row['awrong3']);
        shuffle($slots); //shuffles the answer choices

         //this is where we print the radio buttons
        print ($strQuestionNumber.". <b style='color:red;'>".$row["aquestion"]."</b><br>"); //prints bold questions
        print ("<input type = 'radio' name='test' value =$slots[0]>".$slots[0]."<br>"); //displaying 4 radio buttons with value of answer
        print ("<input type = 'radio' name='test' value =$slots[1]>".$slots[1]."<br>");
        print ("<input type = 'radio' name='test' value =$slots[2]>".$slots[2]."<br>");
        print ("<input type = 'radio' name='test' value =$slots[3]>".$slots[3]."<br>");
        print("<br>");


        array_push($list,$randomInt); //pushes random numbers into an array
```

Here is the link to my page so you can see for yourself:
http://socialsoftware.purchase.edu/nicholas.roberts/mathquiz/mathselect.php?category=Calculus

So basically I want the user to be able to only select one radio box per question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The name of your radio buttons have to be different. If they have the same name, they are all grouped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is stated in the other answer, if there is only one name for all the inputs, they are considered part of the same array.

One possible way around this would be to append `$strQuestionNumber` to `name` in your questions.   like so:

```
 print ("<input type = 'radio' name='test'".$strQuestionNumber." value =$slots[0]>".$slots[0]."<br>");
```

Answer (score 3):

`HTML` will group the radio buttons together if they have the same `name` value. In your case every radio button has the same `name='test'` so they'll all be considered as 'together'.  To be able to select answers for each question you will have to have unique names for the groups. For example `name='test1'` for all radio buttons in question 1 and `name='test9'` for all radio buttons in question 9.

Comment: That totally makes sense! However, how do I correspond radio buttons for questions specifically. Do I need to print the statement ten times? Cause at the moment, its looping the same radio button for each question. How do I make a separate set of radio buttons for each question?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the names of the radio buttons.  All of the buttons for the first question should have the same name (perhaps 'test_q1'); all of the buttons for the second question should have the same name, but a different name than the first set (perhaps 'test_q2'); and so on.

Try this:

```
     //this is where we print the radio buttons
    print ($strQuestionNumber.". <b style='color:red;'>".$row["aquestion"]."</b><br>"); //prints bold questions
    print ("<input type = 'radio' name='test_q" . $strQuestionNumber . "' value =$slots[0]>".$slots[0]."<br>"); //displaying 4 radio buttons with value of answer
    print ("<input type = 'radio' name='test_q" . $strQuestionNumber . "' value =$slots[1]>".$slots[1]."<br>");
    print ("<input type = 'radio' name='test_q" . $strQuestionNumber . "' value =$slots[2]>".$slots[2]."<br>");
    print ("<input type = 'radio' name='test_q" . $strQuestionNumber . "' value =$slots[3]>".$slots[3]."<br>");
    print("<br>");
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Can you check out the comment I left on the first response? I'm not sure how to designate radio buttons for each specific question.

Comment: sure, see the revision.

Answer (score 1):

Just gotta try harder! You got this man.